# SQL Script to find nueric, mixed case and special characters in db column?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to check if the particular db column has one or more of the following characters depending on the condition. I guess there is no api/function in the SQL Server like hasNumericChar() etc. right ? How can we check it ?

1. mixed case (considering sql queries are not case sensitive how can we do this ? )
2. special_chars
3. Numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding rows where a particular column only contains digits:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT column like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Mixed case is going to be tricier:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS AND
                          column like '%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

(Unfortunately, you can't use ranges, like `[a-z]`, since that expands to `aAbBcC`)

What are the special characters?

Comment: @AdaTheDev - unfortunately not (as I edited in, not sure if you saw it). Those ranges mix upper and lower case characters together (e.g. [a-b] == aAb (or is it aBb, I can't remember which, but the point stands))

Comment: if following is the value and i would like to check if it contains the digit "0d90246f17" then LIKE '%[0-9]%' is that right ?

Comment: @Anil Namde - yes, that LIKE check will check that the value contains at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

there is always CHARINDEX function, which can help us to determine if some characters exists in the value